# Connection Lost error while using NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

I am facing connection lost issue while using NSURLConnection. I am using NSURLConnection for asynch download. I am downloading big file of size around 80MB. I am writing received data in file every time with proper file handling. After sometime I am getting error of connection "Connection Lost" in method of NSURLConnection delegate named didFailWithError. If I execute in simulator on Mac then it will take long time but file gets downloaded successfully without having Connection Lost error. Any suggestion how to avoid this error? or what is the reason behind this error?

Let me know if any detail is required. Please note that I have read similar kind of post but it didnt help me.

Comment: can you show related codes ?

Comment: here is a suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926518/how-to-download-large-files-from-web-service-iphone

Answer (score -1):

Find below code snippet and let me know if more information is required:

```
-(void) startDownloadFromURL:(NSString*)URLString
{
    if(URLString == nil)
    {
        [delegate DownloadFailed:-1];
        return;
    }
    //self.pstrBaseFilePath = filePath;
    URLString = [URLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest* pRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [pRequest setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];

    if(gpUserDataManager.pstrSessionID == nil)
        return;

    [pRequest addValue:[@"ASessionID=" stringByAppendingString:gpUserDataManager.pstrSessionID]  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];

    [pRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [pRequest setTimeoutInterval:180];


    self.urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:pRequest delegate:self];

    [urlConnection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    if([httpResponse statusCode] == 200)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        //Start.NOODLE-13304
        /* NSInteger iResponseCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
         NSString* pstrStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", iResponseCode];

         //pTheConnection = nil;

         [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Response Error", @"")
         message:pstrStr
         delegate:nil
         cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"")
         otherButtonTitles:nil]  show];
         */
        [AUserDataManager ProcessResponseCode:httpResponse.statusCode];
        [self.urlConnection cancel];
        [delegate DownloadFailed:httpResponse.statusCode];
        //End.NOODLE-13304
    }

    //[self.pRecvdata setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if(self.recvdData == nil)
    {
        self.recvdData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }

    [self.recvdData appendData:data];
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{

    //    bIsResponseOK = FALSE;
    //
    //    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(SpinEnd) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    //
    //    pTheConnection = nil;

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Connection Error", @"")
                                message:[error localizedDescription]
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"")
                      otherButtonTitles:nil]  show];
    [self.urlConnection cancel];
    [delegate DownloadFailed:-1];

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [connection cancel];
    [delegate DownloadCompleted:self.recvdData];
}

DownloadRequest *request = [[DownloadRequest alloc] init];
request.delegate = self;
[request startDownloadFromURL:strURL];
```